# Dynamically add a Regular Expression to an html Input text Field

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to dynamically add a regular expression (for accepting only positive integers) to an html input text field also created dynamically, using the following, but which does not work:

```
text.setAttribute('pattern', '^[1-9]\d*$')
```

or

```
text.setAttribute('pattern', '[1-9][0-9]*')
```

But the pattern is not being reinforced. Any characters are accepted.

Resolution: In order to set the attribute and a function dynamically, as explained below by Can, one needs to add it as the following:

```
 text.addEventListener('keyup', () => this.validate())
```

It is also possible to use:

```
 text.addEventListener('focusout', () => this.validate())
```

Comment: Small note: You can read and write to the pattern attribute using `text.pattern`.

Comment: Thank you Lemondoge, bu the pattern is not being reinforced in the field. I am able to enter any characters.

Comment: your code works well on google Chrome, are you sure your browser supports the pattern attribute ?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Google Chrome. Are you adding the pattern dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an function and run that with something like onkeyup:

```
(function() {
    var previousValue = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    var pattern = /^\d+$/;
    
    function validateInput(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        var newValue = event.target.value || '';
        console.log(newValue.match(pattern));
        if (newValue.match(pattern)) {
            // Valid input; update previousValue:
            previousValue = newValue;
        } else {
            // Invalid input; reset field value:
            event.target.value = previousValue;
        }
    }
    
    document.getElementById('myInput').onkeyup = validateInput;
}());
```

Check the example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwks4zx9/)

Comment: Yes indeed, it works with a function call. To set the attribute dynamically, one needs to add it as such: text.addEventListener('keyup', () => this.validate())

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, it's actually that the `\` character is escaping the character after it. You need to escape the backslash to make the pattern work.

```js
const f = document.getElementById('form');
const p = '\\d\\d\\d';
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const txt = document.getElementById('text');

f.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}

btn.onclick = () => {
    txt.setAttribute('pattern', p);
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="">
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <button type="submit">
    Go
  </button>
</form>
<p>
  <button id="btn">
    Add Pattern
  </button>
</p>
```

Comment: Yes indeed, one needs to escape the backslash for the pattern to work.